# Cannot truncate table because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I get the following message even when the table that references it is empty: "Cannot truncate table 'dbo.Link' because it is being referenced by a FOREIGN KEY constraint" Doesn't seem to make much sense why this is occurring. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In SQL Server a table referenced by a FK cannot currently be truncated even if all referencing tables are empty or the foreign keys are disabled.

You need to use `DELETE` (may require much more logging) or drop the relationship(s) prior to using `TRUNCATE` and recreate them afterwards or see the workarounds on [this connect item](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/251876/truncate-table-when-fk-are-disable) for a way of achieving this using `ALTER TABLE ... SWITCH`

Comment: thats sounds like quite a poor feature of the product. but i guess will need to factor that into code. thanks

Answer (score 4):

You cannot truncate a table which has an FK constraint on it. As workaround, you could:
1/ Drop the constraints
2/ Trunc the table
3/ Recreate the constraints.

Here it is the associated T-SQL script, supposing you have 2 tables called **MyTable** and **MyReferencedTable**:

```
-- Remove constraint
IF EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE name = 'FK_MyReferencedTable_MyTable')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.MyReferencedTable
    DROP CONSTRAINT FK_MyReferencedTable_MyTable
END


-- Truncate table
TRUNCATE TABLE dbo.MyTable


-- Re-Add constraint
IF NOT EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE name = 'FK_MyReferencedTable_MyTable')
BEGIN
    ALTER TABLE dbo.MyReferencedTable
    WITH CHECK ADD CONSTRAINT [FK_MyReferencedTable_MyTable] FOREIGN KEY(ListingKey)
    REFERENCES dbo.MyTable (ListingKey)
END
```

Answer (score 3):

Execute the following query to search any constraint:

```
use MyDatabase
select c.name as c_name, t.name as t_name
from sys.key_constraints c
join sys.tables t on t.object_id = c.parent_object_id
```

If any constraint found on your table, remove it.

Answer (score 1):

If you are receiving this error and you need to truncate the table then alternative solution could be that you can drop and re-create the table along with 
`primary/other_keys/indexes/triggers`. Please make sure that you don't need to the data in that table.

This soulution is working like a charm for me and hardly took a minute to finish. I am doing it for masking purpose.

Answer (score -2):

Not for SQL Server but MySQL only.

Instead of deleting or recreating the constraint, I prefer this simpler way.
Disable the constraint validation by executing the following query first :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
```

**Then truncate** your tables

And finally, reactivate the constraint validation :

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;
```

Thats a common solution when you migrate databases, so you don't have to worry about the order the tables are inserted in.

Comment: This is not a valid SQL Server setting.

Comment: This is for MySQL and not SqlServer.